# Detect desktop, phone, or tablet in VIsual Basic web app

Tags: asp.net, vba, mobile, web, webforms

I'm currently working on a Visual Basic web app. The app should send the user to a mobile version of the site if they are accessing it from a phone. However, if it is a tablet (or desktop), it should still go to the full site.

Here is what I have so far but it doesn't account for differing pixel densities and whatnot.

```
If Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth < 600 And Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsHeight < 1024 And Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice Then
        Response.Redirect("http://localhost:9999/mobile")
End If
```

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

this site has a practical example, that I am applying on a website, Greetings

[Example Link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Detect-Mobile-Browser-Mobile-Device-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Comment: Which part of this determines if it is a tablet or phone?